# SignalR - Why is another hub's Disconnect method invoked when a user reloads the page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

**Background:**

I'm having trouble figuring out why Disconnect is called from a hub that's not yet been initialized.

I have two different MVC views that creates different signal connections:

- ListView  (JS creates a connection to ListHub which does **not** implement IDisconnect)
- DetailsView (JS creates a connection to DetailsHub which **does** implement IDisconnect)

When a user logs on, he/she is redirected to the ListView where a javascript creates a connection to the ListHub so that the page is aware of events that locks/unlocks items in the list. When the user clicks on an item, a signal is sent to the ListHub and the item is locked by the user. After that, I stop the click from doing the GET request by using event.preventDefault() and it works well.

**The problem is...**
Once the user leaves for another page - or if the page simply is reloaded - the Disconnect method of the *DetailsHub* is triggered. I don't get why this is happening. Remember, the ListHub is the only active hub thus far. No other Hubs or connections have been initialized. Still, this is the behavior I'm getting.

**What I'm trying to achieve**

What I'm trying to achieve here is to do something when Disconnect is raised/called on the DetailsHub. I want nothing to happen when the user disconnects from the ListHub.

Answer (score 1):

It's written in signalR project's wiki:

> Whenever a client disconnects, the Disconnect method will be invoked on all hubs that implement IDisconnect. When this method is called you can use Context.ConnectionId to access the client that disconnected.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

Comment: is there other way to just disconnect that client. It will interrupt all the connected client.